# Is there a good set of heuristics around how/when to use optional parameters

Tags: functions, parameters

using a python function signature as an example:

```
def this_function_has_an_optional_parameter(x, y = 42): ...
```

I'm wondering if there is an existing set of guidelines specifically for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is that you use optional parameters when a default value for that parameter makes sense.

A common guideline is that if you do the same thing three times, you are repeating yourself and should consider refactoring. So if that function is called three times with y=42, and once with another value, you could consider 42 to be the default and add an optional parameter to simplify your code BUT that might be hiding important information. Use an optional parameter when hiding that extra information improves the clarity of what you're doing.